# How to check for existing entity when saving changes to a database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm looking at a way to check for existing entries in a database prior to creating a new one.

I have a very simple table `Person` that has two values `RowId` and `UserId`. These are not the same value, `UserId` is a value from an external service and could potentially be anything, `RowId` is the unique identifier in my system.

When saving and model object that has a `Person` as a foreign object I would like to populate the object using the `UserId` and, upon saving the object, check if a record with that `UserId` exists and if it does then use that one instead of creating a new one.

I had thought about overriding the `SaveChanges()` method in my `DbContext` but not sure if this can be done here.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about this or would I be better off implementing the login into my controllers?

I thought I'd show how I'm currently doing things to put it into context:

**Controller:**

```
public MvcHtmlString UpdatePanelDetails(int id, FormCollection values)
{

    Panel panel = db.Panels.Find(id);

    bool worked = TryUpdateModel(panel,values);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(panel).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new MvcHtmlString("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("Failed");
    }
}
```

Within this `Panel` model I have my `Person` object. Within my view I have a lookup to the external person system that populates a hidden textbox that is bound to `Person.UserId` so when it comes to the `TryUpdateModel` the `Person` is bound to the `Panel` but has a `RowId` of 0.

What I would like is to be able to have a single location that could populate the correct `RowId` (if the person already exists) which is why I was looking at overriding the `SaveChanges` method.

I'm now thinking that isn't possible and would be better for me to do it as part of my person lookup and have two hidden textboxes.

Comment: why cannot you make a search in the Db for that userId?. if you don't get any record for that, create it otherwise populate it

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that `RowId` and `UserId` are a composite primary key for your `Person` table. This means that trying to save an entry that already exists would raise an `Exception` because of the **unique constraint**. You can handle this exception and use the value, as it won't be saved as a duplicate entry.

```
try
{
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // If the unique constraint is violated you end up here.
}
```

In order to not handle an `Exception` you can do the following:

```
var person = DbContext.Persons.Where(p => p.UserId == userId).SingleOrDefault();
if (person == null)
{
    DbContext.Persons.Add(new Person(userId));
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to cause an exception, I ideally want it to silently use the one that already exists in the database.

Comment: @AverageMarcus In this case you can issue a select for the entry and see whether it's count is 1.

Comment: I have updated my question with a bit of an example of what I am trying to achieve.